# Why can't I access adapter submitList() method from within onChanged()?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

Can someone tell me why the submitList() method can't be accessed in the following code? Similar code is working fine in another test app, although that's in an Activity.

```
public class MyFFBooksFragment extends Fragment {

       private int currentBook;
       private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
       private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
       private GamebookViewModel gamebookViewModel;

       @Nullable
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
       ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

               View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myffbooks_fragment, container, false);

               mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

               final ArrayList<BookItem> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
               final BookItemAdapter maAdapter = new BookItemAdapter(bookList);

               mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
               mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
               mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
               mRecyclerView.setAdapter(maAdapter);

               gamebookViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GamebookViewModel.class);
               gamebookViewModel.getAllGamebooks().observe(this, new Observer<List<Gamebook>>() {

               @Override
               public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Gamebook> gamebooks) {
                       maAdapter.submitList(bookList);
               }
           });

    return view;
   }
 }
```

Comment: is the submitList function private?

Comment: No, it's not my own method. submitList() is part of the Android API. It's a member method of the PagerListAdapter class

Comment: What's the error exactly?

Comment: "Cannot resolve method submitList". It's in red in the editor so won't compile. The method doesn't seem to be available on autocomplete when I type the adapter name mAdapter.

Comment: check your imports maybe your adapter extends the wrong class

Comment: Thanks, but everything looks okay on the imports side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should not use it in **onCreateView()**. Try use call method that triggers observation of VM after an Activity had been created, near **onStart()**. Maybe it will help.

> When a new page is available, we call submitList() method of the PagedListAdapter class

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    gamebookViewModel.callFunc()
}
```

Also as I understand, you call **getAllGamebooks()** which triggers some actions and return you ***LiveData<*>*** and you subscribe on it with **observe()**. I recommend you to separate this on 2 methods:

1. subscribe
2. action

Answer (score 0):

Use PagedList instead of list like below:

```
gamebookViewModel.getAllGamebooks().observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<Gamebook>>() {

           @Override
           public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<Gamebook> gamebooks) {
                   maAdapter.submitList(bookList);
           }
       });
```

And in your viewmodel too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions everyone. I'll try them out when work quietens down and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. My adapter wasn't extending ListAdapter, so no wonder it couldn't find the submitList() method. Rookie error.